# Looking for tighter bounds on a certain solution of a nonlinear equation

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, lower-bounds

I have to solve an equation which is $$\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = \sum_{i=1}^N y_i,$$ where
$$x_i = \frac{z_i}{1 + (K_i - 1) w}$$  and $$y_i = \frac{K_i z_i}{1 + (K_i - 1) w}.$$

The $z_i$ are all positive and add to $1$; the $K_i$ are positive but range from very small to very large (at least, one is strictly greater than $1$ and one is strictly smaller than $1$).

The solution ($w$) looked for is between two vertical asymptotes corresponding to $-1 / (K_{\text{max}} - 1)$ (which is negative) and $1 / (1 - K_{\text{min}})$ (which is greater than $1$). Considering the fact that, at solution, all $x_i$ and $y_i$ must be positive and smaller than $1$ (since they both must add to $1$), I have been able to find a left bound corresponding to the maximum value of $\dfrac{K_i z_i - 1}{K_i-1}$ (considering only the $K_i > 1$) and a right bound corresponding to the minimum value of $\dfrac{1 - z_i}{1 - K_i}$ (considering only the $K_i < 1$). These bounds are inside the asymptotes but I need a tighter interval.

I have not been able to go further. Any help will be more than welcome.

Comment: Why must $\sum x_i$ equal 1?  I get that it equals $1/(2-w)$. Note that $y_i = K_i x_i$, then sum the equation $x_i(1+(K_i-1)w)=z_i$ over $i$ and apply $\sum x_i=\sum y_i$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay. At solution, the sum of the x[i]'s and the sum of the y[i]'s must be equal to 1. Each of these quantities will be computable and computed when the solution (w) looked for will be obtained.

Comment: Sorry, I miscalculated.

Comment: A colleague of mine, [Leonardo Robol](http://poisson.phc.unipi.it/compiled-pdf/robol-thesis.pdf), defended a thesis on the numerical solution of this kind of equations as a method to compute eigenvalues and polynomial zeros.

Answer (score 3):

The equation rewrites as
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{(K_i-1)z_i}{1+(K_i-1)w}=0,$$
or with $a_i=1/(1-K_i)$,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{z_i}{w-a_i}=0.
\end{equation}
Let $Q(w)$ be the monic polynomial of degree $N$ with roots the $a_i$'s, and $P(w)$ some polynomial of degree $N-1$. Assuming all the $a_i$'s are distinct, we have
$$\frac{P(w)}{Q(w)}=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{P(a_i)}{Q'(a_i)}\frac{1}{w-a_i}.$$
If we choose $P(w)$ as the unique interpolating polynomial such that
$$P(a_i)=z_iQ'(a_i),\qquad i=1,\ldots,N,$$
the equation simply becomes
$$P(w)=0,$$
which has exactly $N-1$ roots. Assume that $$0<K_{1}<\cdots K_i<1<K_{i+1}<\cdots<K_N$$ 
so that
$$a_{i+1}<\cdots<a_N<0<a_1<\cdots<a_i.$$
Since, by assumption, the $z_i$'s are positive, the signs of the $P(a_{i+1}), P(a_{i+2}),\ldots,P(a_i)$ alternate and thus each of the intervals $(a_{i+1},a_{i+2}),\ldots,(a_{i-1},a_i)$ contains exactly one root of the equation. A lower bound for the smallest root is $a_{i+1}=1/(1-K_{i+1})$, and an upper bound for the largest root is $a_i=1/(1-K_i)$.